# Running Django runserver doesn't respond on the browser

Tags: centos6, python, django

I've create a project in a server with CentOS, Django 1.10.1 and using python 3.5.

When I run in the terminal py `manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` it shows

> Performing system checks...
>
> System check identified no issues (0 silenced). December 10, 2017 -
>   15:45:23 Django version 1.10.1, using settings 'samplepy35.settings'
>   Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/ Quit the server
>   with CONTROL-C.

When I use the command `netstat -tuplen` it says that python is listening on PORT 8000.

But when I try to access on the browser it doesn't respond.

What can the problem be?

Comment: where is this server hosted ? is this on your desktop or cloud ?

Comment: cloud. But I already solved the problem.